# Why inconsistent results using sqrt in reduce?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Consider the following code in Spark that should return the sum of the sqrt's of a sequence of integers:

```
// Create an RDD of a sequence of integers
val data = sc.parallelize(Range(0,100))

// Transform RDD to sequence of Doubles
val x = data.map(_.toDouble)

// Reduce the sequence as the sum of the sqrt of each integer 
// (repeated 10 times with each result stored as a kv pair)
val xReduceMultipleTimes = Range(0,10).map(n=>(n, x.reduce((x,y)=>x+Math.sqrt(y))))
```

The reduce operation is repeated multiple times, sequentially, on the same RDD, and should return the same result each time. However, the output I'm getting from Spark is inconsistent, and nowhere near the correct value.

```
xReduceMultipleTimes: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(Int, Double)] =
Vector((0,105.44288170056565), (1,245.5267945723869), (2,190.04459651854287),
(3,233.32211443903282), (4,190.04459651854287), (5,105.44288170056566), 
(6,273.5022316153404), (7,105.44288170056568), (8,105.44288170056566), 
(9,205.51799497636216))
```

The correct result should be `661.463`, as verified with Mathematica.

Replacing `Math.sqrt(y)` with `y` yields the correct and consistent sum of the *unrooted* integers (i.e. `4950`).

Any ideas as to what could be causing the inconsistency?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Square root is not associative. Keep in mind that `reduce` does two things, it first reduces locally, where the first parameter is indeed the accumulator and the second is the new value. The next thing it does is merge the intermediate results, this results in an accumulator added to the square root of the node value....not what you want. To do this, you must use `aggregate`

```
rdd.aggregate(0)((accum, value) => accum + Math.sqrt(value), _ + _)
```

I believe this captures your intent. The first param is the seed of 0, then is a function that is run locally on each node. Then the addition is merely adding up the nodes, which do not need to be square rooted.

Comment: The other way to change your original code would be to do the square root calculation in the second step when you map over the RDD to convert the values to doubles.